# How do I know that the charms bar has been closed in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am currently developing a windows 8 metro app in that I want to pause my app (Basically game) when charms bar opens up that I am doing :

```
CustomSettingFlyout.Show();  
PauseGame();
```

But after user closes the Charm bar I want to resume my game.I thought there would be an event that says that the charms has been closed, but that's not the case. What's the correct way of to get charms bar got closed?

I also tried this :-

```
Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
```

Added this in main class's Constructor

```
void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.CodeActivated)
    {
        if (CharmsActivated)
        {
            CharmBar.IsOpen = true;
            CharmsActivated = false;
            ResumeGame();
        }
    }
    if (e.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
    {
        if (CharmBar.IsOpen == true)
        {
            CharmsActivated = true;
            CharmBar.IsOpen = false;
            PauseGame();
        }
    }
}
```

But that is not working.Please tell me if there is another way to do this.
(C#, XAML, Windows 8.1 app)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in there to see if any event fires at all.

Comment: I tried,I think I am not able to get the event at all.I don't know whats happening wrong.